# Implementing Content-Security-Policy on Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, content-security-policy

On Apache 2.2 I'm about to set up Content-Security-Policy to allow browsers coming from one particular domain to load data into iframes from a certain virtual host.

```
$ httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
$ httpd -S -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

I Believe this directive should do the trick:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors *.requestorsdomain.no"
```

Problem: Where will I insert it in the httpd.conf?
I placed it within  in httpd.conf and it seems to be accepted syntactically after a restart.

httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/app/httpd/html">  
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors *.requestorsdomain.no"  
</Directory>
```

The particular virtual server that should allow iframes is included at the end of httpd.conf
and is passing on to a Jboss on the same server.

```
Include virtual.d/*.conf   
../virtual.d/rolf.conf:  
ProxyPass /rolf/ http://rolfhost:8080/rolf/  
ProxyPassReverse /rolf/ http://rolfhost:8080/rolf/
```

Furthermore, all is behind a BlueCoat Reverse proxy, allowing Internet Incoming.

So, in summary:
It does not work. Client can't still load into iframes. Probably Headers get stuck or are not served correctly.
How to do it correctly?
Will I need to apply CSP passing in Blue Coat as well?

Thank You, help is highly appreciated.